# GnuCOBOL trivial "echo" function

Tags: gnucobol

How to create X ANY LENGTH functions for string processing? Trivial (in other languages) "echo-reply" does something unexpected. Documentation, open resources and FAQ https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#id362 did not help.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. stdtest.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC
       FUNCTION REPLY.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 tst BINARY-SHORT UNSIGNED.
       01 expected PIC S9(6)V9(4) USAGE COMP.
       01 argA PIC S9(6)V9(4) USAGE COMP.
       01 argB PIC S9(6)V9(4) USAGE COMP.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       *> must print whole string instead of first 8 chars
       DISPLAY FUNCTION REPLY("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog").
       STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM stdtest.

   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   FUNCTION-ID. REPLY.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.
   DATA DIVISION.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 argument PIC X ANY LENGTH.
       01 result.
           05 argument-pointer USAGE POINTER.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BY REFERENCE argument RETURNING result.
       *> https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#id362
       MOVE argument TO result.
   END FUNCTION REPLY.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample results in 8 characters as the returning group is (on your machine) 8 bytes long (because of the `POINTER` below it). It compiles without errors as you only reference the group item, which is an implied alphanumeric(-group)-item (or national-group-item, if you add `USAGE NATIONAL`)

The way to do this with (recent) "standard" COBOL is a variable-length `RETURNING` item.
The options provided by the standard for functions are `DYNAMIC LENGTH` (ideal version, but not supported with GnuCOBOL yet) or a variable-length group (`OCCURS 0 TO ... DEPENDING ON`) that is big enough to hold the data.
The following sample *should* work (but results in an internal [codegen] error which should be fixed with upcoming 3.1rc1):

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       FUNCTION-ID. REPLY.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       77 arg-len   USAGE BINARY-LONG.
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 argument  PIC X ANY LENGTH.
       01 result.
          05 filler PIC X OCCURS 0 to 99999 DEPENDING ON arg-len.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BY REFERENCE argument RETURNING result.
           MOVE FUNCTION LENGTH (argument) TO arg-len
           MOVE argument TO result.
       END FUNCTION REPLY.
```

Note: You find the bug report and a patch for a potential fix in the GnuCOBOL issue tracker as [#641](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/bugs/641).

Comment: I've extended your example by OCCURS 0 TO UNBOUNDED TIMES which is less hardcoding, and an allocation of internal buffer. Both of them work with predefined TIMES and fail with DEPENDING ON. The codegen error occurs on GC 2.2 and on the latest nightly GC 3.1-dev. 
In short, an answer is **No way**. Anyway, thank you for clarification.

Comment: The answer is not "no way" but "needs an unreleased version", see the bug-reference edited in for a patch.
I'd suggest to not use `UNBOUNDED` as this would allocate the maximum buffer on entering the function (something around 950MB)...

Comment: :) Same thing for GC users. UNBOUNDED must not reserve 1Gb of nothing. Correct implementation of Map or List you may find in other languages. Map<Index,Group> fits "an unrestricted upper limit" a little bit better then ArrayList<Index, Group>. The misses may return NULL pointers, the sequence is up to a programmer.

Comment: That is the result of `DYNAMIC LENGTH` in COBOL, but GnuCOBOL hasn't implemented this yet (patches welcome).
`OCCURS UNBOUNDED` is an IBM extension and the length (and normally also the allocation) must be done manually. Note: GC will use the ODO-maximum soon - still too much for most cases but better than "always 1GB".